# MMAP fails in attempt to double buffer framebufer

Tags: linux, mmap

I am trying to implement a double buffer using ioctl(fd, FBIOPAN_DISPLAY...
my single buffer code works fine

```
screensize = vinfo.xres * vinfo.yres * vinfo.bits_per_pixel / 8;

fbp = (char*)mmap(0, screensize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fbfd, 0);
```

when I try to increase the "length parameter" by using screensize*2, the `mmap` fails with `EINVAL`.  I think it doesn't like my length parameter.

The screen size for a single buffer is 6,220,800 and for the double buffer is 12,441600.  This is an embedded system but it has 1 Gig of RAM.

The length parameter is size_t which on this system is only 4 bytes which would make me think that the max size I could use would be 4 Meg, yet 6 Meg works fine so I think I am missing something really simple. Is there a way to `mmap` a buffer larger than size_t?

Comment: what do you mean 'increase'. are you saying remapping?

Comment: by increase, I mean that I recompile and run with that second param (length) = screensize*2.  It fails with the EINVAL errno

Comment: have you tried just create a const var as double_screensize = screensize*2 and then pass it to mmap?

Answer (score 1):

[The man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) says that length (the 2nd parameter) is of type `size_t`, so I don't think you are safe to pass a larger type.

I would suggest you to just map the first part, and then remap the second part as shown [in this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35891525/mmap-for-writing-sequential-log-file-for-speed/35891885#35891885).

Regarding the `EINVAL`:
Following is stated in the man page:

> EINVAL
>       We don't like addr, length, or offset (e.g., they are too large, or not aligned on a page boundary).
>
> EINVAL
>       (since Linux 2.6.12) length was 0.
>
> EINVAL
>       flags contained neither MAP_PRIVATE or MAP_SHARED, or contained both of these values.

Are you sure you are page alligned?

Comment: Which param needs to be page-aligned?  Since the first and last params are 0, I figured I was but do I need to modify my length value to be cleanly divisible by a page size?

Comment: if using  screensize is successful and therefore page-aligned.  I would think that screensize*2 would also be page-aligned if needed

Comment: Okay, that's correct. But what comes to my mind: If `screensize * 2` is larger than `size_t`, then an arithmetic overflow occurs, which may result in undefined behaviour. But I also don't think that this is the problem, because 12,441,600 is far more smaller than 4,294,967,295 (assuming size_t is uint).